# reading from a file until EOF

Tags: java

I have a txt file that a bit per line now i want to modify it so i can have it rrun through

entire collection '10101010' per line instead of just '1' per line...
I have a string that will be added in to an array list and perform with the string

```
'
  1
  0
  0
  1
  1
  0
  0
  1

'


Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = getInput.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            stringData += scanner.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stringData.length(); i++) {

            list.add((Integer.valueOf(stringData.substring(i, i + 1))));

            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        }
```

Comment: did you mean you want to re-write the `.txt` file with 8bit per line?

Comment: Where are you having trouble with your program?

Comment: What is `stringData`? It looks wrong. What output to you actually want?

Comment: that the txt file has 1 bit per line, but now i want it read a whole binarynumber '0101010101' like this

Comment: Just want an ArrayList called List to get a string 101010101 per line instead of just '1' bit per line

Answer (score 0):

I believe you over thought your implementation, it's much simpler to skip the `List<Integer>` -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  String fileName = getInput.nextLine();

  File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {     // Check for an int. With a Scanner there is no
                                     // need for getting the input one line at a time.
    sb.append(scanner.nextInt());    // Append it (as an int) to the StringBuilder.
  }
  System.out.println(sb.toString()); // Print it on one line.
}
```

I tested this,

```
$ pwd
/home/efrisch
$ cat input.txt
1
0
1
0
1
```

Output was

```
/home/efrisch/input
10101
```